# VBA multiple For loops - works right only first two times

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been working on this little piece of code for a couple of days now and have hit a snag that I just cannot figure out. Basically  I have a nested for loop that is supposed to take values from one Sheet and put them in a data sheet so that those value can be saved and averaged out over time.
I want the data from the cells M5 - M35 to get put into the data sheet like this: from left to right A3 - AC200, but I also want the loop to stop once the M5 - M35 range runs out of values and when the user next pushes the button to store data I want the loop to start on the next line down.

So This Spreadsheet is for my work, it is for a Butchery Yield Test and I want it to have it's owned database stored on a hidden sheet that will be averaged out over time so I or others can come back to it and update it every few months to make the averages more accurate and to get a better understanding of the profitability of certain cuts of meat.

I have tried setting the loop values back to their starting values once the loop has filled out all the data which worked and I thought I'd solved the issue until I ran the test multiple time and found that the first and second time work as expected from the third onwards however it *doesn't start the loop down at the next row* it just continues through the range

[image: Screen capture of what is happening]

```
Sub subData1()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rcell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Tws As Worksheet

    Set Tws = Worksheets("Test")
    Set ws = Worksheets("data")

    For i = 3 To 200 'range is from cell A3 - A200

        'if start cell already has value go down a row
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            i = i + 1
        End If

        'set the range for data sheet
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, 30).End(xlToRight))

        For f = 5 To 35

            For Each rcell In rng 'loop through each cell in data sheet range

                If rcell.Value = "" Then 'if cell is blank input data

                    If Tws.Cells(f, 13).Value <> "" Then

                        'Check the selected Cell has a value
                        rcell.Value = Tws.Cells(f, 13).Value
                        f = f + 1

                    End If

                Else

                    If f > 5 Then
                        MsgBox "Data Storage Updated", , "Data Storage"
                        f = 5
                        Exit Sub

                    'Else
                        'MsgBox "Value Must Be Greater Than Zero", , f
                        'f = 5
                        'Exit Sub

                    End If

                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your loop and logic will greatly benefit with a short block of code before the loop to determine where the [last row of data](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) exists. Using that `lastRow` value (plus one) will get you straight to the first unused row to use for the destination. One of the problems your code has is that you're incrementing the `i` variable that is automatically incremented by the `for loop`. Everything will get confused if you do that.

Comment: In addition to @PeterT 's comment, I would change your for loops to `Do While i <= 200` and `Do While f <= 35`. Then, before each relevant loop set `i = 3` and `f = 5`. Also, at the last lines of the loops you add the increments of `i = i + 1` and `f = f + 1`

Comment: You should NEVER manipulate the iterator within the for-loop.

Comment: I'm really trying hard to understand what you are actually trying to achieve. Can you give a better example and show both sheets?

Comment: PeterT I will try what you've suggested and let you know how I get on, I did initially leave it up to the for loop to increment the 'i' and 'f' values but it wasn't doing anything so to get it to work (kind of atleast) I had to add the increments in I felt like it was unnecessary but I'm pretty new to VBA so wasn't sure if maybe loops just work a little different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's working the first and second time is because of this line

```
If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
    i = i + 1
End If
```

But, if you'll notice, it's only running once for each iteration. Which means that on a blank sheet, it will evaluate false on the first iteration of the first run and continue, on the first iteration of the second run, it will evaluate true and move down one row to row 4, but on the first iteration of the third run it will also evaluate true and move down to row 4 and then place data starting at `ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, 30).End(xlToRight))`

You need to change your `If-End If` to a function that will retrieve the last used row in Column A of your data sheet. Additionally, you probably don't need your outer `For-Next` loop since that's looping through your output sheet and would output the same `M5:M35` values for every single row.

If I understand your needs correctly, I believe you could utilize this to accomplish what you're looking for

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Tws As Worksheet

Dim endRow As Long

Set Tws = Worksheets("Test")
Set ws = Worksheets("data")

endRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set rng = ws.Cells(endRow, 1)

For f = 5 To 35
    If Tws.Cells(f, 13).Value <> "" Then
        rng.Value = Tws.Cells(f, 13).Value
        Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
Next
```

With this, every sequential button click would insert data at a new row, looping through `Tws.Cells(f,13)` and placing that value in the right-most column by incrementally setting the range.

Comment: Thank you, your code works perfectly to what I was after

Comment: Happy to have helped.